# Can't add ABPerson to ABGroup. No errors, just will not actually add

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, abaddressbook

Hey I'm trying to add an ABPerson to an ABGroup. I get no errors or anything. My output tells me the person has been added successfully.

```
if(ABGroupAddMember(self.group, [allContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], &error))
            NSLog(@"Added person: %@ to group: %@", ABRecordCopyCompositeName([allContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]), ABRecordCopyCompositeName(self.group));

if(ABAddressBookSave(self.addressBook, &error))
        NSLog(@"Commited changes.");
```

These two statements return the correct output.

But upon querying the group members, I get an empty array.

```
NSLog(@"%@", ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(self.group)); //returns null
```

If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow not 5 minutes after posting, I've found the problem. After editing the group, I have to add it back to the address book like so:

```
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error);

if(ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error))
    NSLog(@"Commited changes.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an FYI, some sources (ABSource, e.g. MSExchange) do not support group creation.

There are some details and code examples on specifying sources (iOS 4+ only) here:
[Obtaining Specific ABSource from ABAddressBook in iOS 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679641/obtaining-specific-absource-from-abaddressbook-in-ios-4)